# OnePageCheckout JS breaking for Internet Explorer 11 only after upgrade

Tags: onepage-checkout, error, javascript, upgrade

Recently upgraded from `Magento CE 1.5` to `Magento 1.9.0.1`. I kept the original 1.5 custom theme which was done by someone else. Starting receiving emails a few days later from customers on `IE11` who were complaining of the checkout "freezing up" or not allowing them to continue. Here is a screenshot of what the customer sees.

[image: friggin problem]

I fired up `IE11` and opened the inspector which revealed the following errors;

[image]

After comparing the console errors to Chrome and Firefox, I determined that the errors present in IE11 but not in others. The error is:

> Unable to get property 'reject' of undefined or null reference.

After some Googling, this seems to be a very ambiguous error. Has anyone experienced a similar problem after upgrading? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

deprecation.js is not part of magento and prototype might not be IE11 compatible https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/3508-ie11-support